# NodeJs, Spawn convert

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick, spawn

I want to execute `convert` inside **Node** using `spawn`.
this command runs without any error :

```
var args = [
  'img1.jpg',
  'img2.jpg',
  '-gravity', 'center',
  '-composite', '-'
];

var ls = spawn('convert',args);
ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

but when I try this one :

```
var args = [
  'img1.jpg',
  '\\( img2.jpg -resize 10x10 \\)',
  '-gravity', 'center',
  '-composite', '-'
];
var ls = spawn('convert',args);
ls.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
   console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

getting this Error:

```
stderr: convert: unable to open image `\( img2.jpg -resize 10x10 \)': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2702.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format `JPG -RESIZE 10X10 \)' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert: no images defined `-' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3257.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the Answer:
arguments must be splitted all:

```
var args = [
  'img1.jpg',
  '\\(','img2.jpg','-resize','10x10','\\)',
  '-gravity', 'center',
  '-composite', '-'
];
```

Comment: nice! I was having a similar issue using .execFile. My issue was for the arguments I had "-resize 10x10" as one array item instead of splitting them into two arguments.